# How to configure Tomcat v8.0 server in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am using Eclipse Juno and I've installed Apache Tomcat/8.0.0-RC5 in my PC via windows installer. When I try to define a new server in Eclipse, under Apache, I don't have Tomcat v8.0 option. It stops at Tomcat v7.0. How can I get Apache Tomcat v8.0 running in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Keep an eye on http://bugs.eclipse.org/422298 . Support for 8.0 hasn't been added just yet.